# How to find family of functions

Tags: analysis, dimension-theory-analysis

I want to find the family of functions with this property:

$$\epsilon F\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)=\epsilon^r F(x)\quad\text{with}\  x,\epsilon, r \in \mathbb{R}$$ ($\epsilon$ and r are constants)

An example of those functions is $F(x)=x^{1-r}$. Is the only one I found. Some other examples of members different from this one would be useful.

An equivalent problem is to find the functions $F'{(x)}=\epsilon^r F'{(\epsilon\cdot x)}$

If the function has a Taylor series  $F{(x)}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i x^i$ then it follows $\epsilon F{(\frac{x}{\epsilon})}\,=\,\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i \frac{x^i}{\epsilon^{i-1}}\,=\,\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i \epsilon^r x^i$

From the definition, if $A{(x)}$ and $B{(x)}$ belong to the family, then any linear combination of A and B also belong to the family.

If $F{(x)}$ is an area, then that area has fractional dimension r according to the definition of [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension).

Comment: Let $\epsilon = x$.

Comment: $\epsilon$ should be restricted to positive values, for example because $\epsilon^r$ with $r$ real is undefined when $\epsilon < 0$.